# How should I avoid to grow the last item to full width ? FlexBoxLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I want the items of the recyclerview to stretch equally and distribute the space equally, It working fine but the last item of the recyclerview is stretching in full width, I want it to stretch like the item above and stay at the start

Following is the what I did :

```
        flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

And in adapter for layout grow I did this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
                if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
                    FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
                    flexboxLp.setFlexGrow(1.0f);
                }
```

Here is what I am getting (Last Item) :

http://prntscr.com/pa4rj5

And here is what I want to achieve (Last Item):

http://prntscr.com/pa4rue

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is do not use a library as its main intention is make content Justifyied, `flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);`
you can try by this : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/
or try this

```
val flexboxLayoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(this)
flexboxLayoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
flexboxLayoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.FLEX_START
```

// flexboxLayoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.SPACE_EVENLY

Comment: In other words you are suggesting that I should use ItemDecorator with recyclerview instead of FlexBoxLayoutManger ?

Comment: Yes, or you can use Grid layout in place of Recycleview.

Comment: No, cannot do that, Already tried that, Because this approach doesn't work for all devices and all possible cases

Comment: I hope your problem is resolved, if not then look one more time i have updated code.